# Will be staying or Will Stay?

Tags: grammar, tenses

He will stay here for a week .

He will be staying here for a week.

I will be staying here till he comes back.

I will stay here till he comes back.

Are the above written sentences correct? And, when do we use will stay and will be staying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All four sentences are grammatically correct.
"Will stay" and "will be staying" can be used interchangeably; there is only a subtle difference. "Will" is more simple, more in the immediate present and less flexible ("I will stay right here!"),"Will be staying" implies the future, and is more flexible ("I will be staying at his house while I look for a new place to live.")